# ETH-Hardness of $Gap\text-MAX\text-3SAT_{c}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, np-hardness, np-complete, p-vs-np

The PCP theorem can be stated like this :

There is a polynomial time reduction from SAT to  $Gap\text-MAX\text-3SAT_{c}$ i.e. there is a reduction that maps an instance $\phi$ of SAT to an instance $\psi$ of  $Gap\text-MAX\text-3SAT_{c}$ such that

- If $\phi$ is satisfiable, so is $\psi$.
- If $\phi$ is unsatisfiable, then $OPT(\psi) \leq c$, i.e., there is no assignment to the variables of $\psi$ that satisfies more than a fraction $c$ of the  clauses.

What is the blow-up of this reduction? That is, what are the parameters of the instanceof  $Gap\text-MAX\text-3SAT_{c}$ in terms of parameter of the given instance of SAT. Is the blow-up linear?

Comment: [Moshkovitz-Raz](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~ranraz/publications/Ptwo-prover.pdf) appears to give a "quasiquadratic" blow-up, $O(n^{2+o(1)})$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Does the blow-up not depend on the choice of $c$? Intuitively, I would guess that as $c$ gets closer to 7/8, the blow-up gets larger. Is this not correct?

Comment: This indeed sounds likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best known result is that the blow-up can be quasi-linear (the new instance has size $n\cdot(\log n)^{O(1)}$). This is given in [Dinur's 2007 paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~toni/Courses/PCP/handouts/pcp-dinur.pdf) (Thm 8.1), which is also cited by the Moshkovitz-Raz paper mentioned by Yuval Filmus.

As far as I know it is still open if the blow-up can be brought down to linear. Some people call this the Linear PCP conjecture, see e.g. the [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04935) by Bonnet, Egri and Marx

Comment: Assuming such hypothesis can we prove that Approximating Exact-set cover is ETH-hard? http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37461/is-approximating-exact-set-cover-np-hard-for-constant-approximation-factor-eth

Answer (score 1):

[Theorem 7](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05991.pdf#page=5) achieves polylogarithmic blow-up. ​ As the footnote at the end of the previous page alludes to, there's a simple *randomized* reduction which goes from m clauses to O(n) clauses and preserves satisfying assignments with certainty. ​ Based on that paper's discussion of Gap-ETH (Hypothesis 5 and the page after that), nothing tighter seems to be known. ​ Also see [Corollary 11](http://people.csail.mit.edu/dmoshkov/papers/two-prover/two-prover-full.pdf#page=7).

Comment: assuming Hypothesis 5 can we prove ETH-hardness of approximating Exct set cover.  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37461/is-approximating-exact-set-cover-np-hard-for-constant-approximation-factor-eth

Comment: We can do that even without "assuming Hypothesis 5", since since even _finding a feasible solution_ to the linked problem is ETH-hard. ​ ​

Comment: Which linked problem? Can you send me a reference for that too?

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/37461/6973 . ​ No, but I just wrote it up there. ​ ​ ​ ​